# How to display an image if the value has a decimal point?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Basically in my in my aspx page I have a gridview which displays the value from my database as an image. So if a value in my database table is 5, it will be displayed as 5 images in the gridview. ie.(star.jpg star.jpg star.jpg star.jpg star.jpg)

The code:

```
Protected Function getrating(ByVal rate As Integer)
        Dim getrating As String
        getrating = ""
        For i = 1 To rate
            getrating = getrating + "<img src=""Images/star.jpg"" alt=""*"">"
        Next
        Return getrating
    End Function
```

It's been working fine so far for whole numbers, but now I'm adding averages into my database, so any value with a decimal point(like 4.6) gives me the error

```
"Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid."
```

How would I go about in adding images when the value has a decimal point?

Since the field in my database has the range set to numbers 1 to 5, I like it to display another image if the value has a decimal point. ie. "3.5" would display in the gridview star.jpg, star.jpg, star.jpg, halfstar.jpg. If that made any sense lol.

Anyone have an idea on how  to do doing this?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if you have a fractional part? You could multiple the value by 10, then check if the value modulo 10 is zero. If not, you have a fractional part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your error, it's probable that you're not even accepting decimal values and inserting the `NULL` value when they occur. Fix that first, make sure the result isn't `DBNull`, then you can make the changes to a decimal type like `Double`:

```
Protected Function GetRating(ByVal rating As Double) As String
    Dim result As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    While rating >= 1.0#
        result.Append("<img src=""Images/star.jpg"" alt=""*"">")
        rating -= 1.0#
    End While

    If rating > 0.0# Then _
        result.Append("<img src=""Images/halfstar.jpg"" alt=""1/2"">")

    Return result.ToString()
End Function
```

I also took the liberty of using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `DBNull` value (From error description).

```
If reader.Read() Then
  IF Not reader.IsDBNull(0) Then '1st column
    'If field type is decimal
     Dim decimalVar=reader.GetDecimal(0)
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this I really recommend to use one image which contains all stars in it. So that image should have 5 Stats like:

[image]

For this demo I added a image with 120px width and 24px height. Then You need to add a  like this:

Then when you want to show your stars, you need to find out the width of this  with following method:

```
DIV width = (Rate/5) * 120
```

So for example 2.5 will be (2.5/5)*120 = 60! Then you need to change DIV's width to 60 and then you'll have your 2.5 rank! and will become something like:

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://s.codeproject.com/script/Ratings/Images/stars-fill.png);width:60px;height:24px;">
</div>
```

This is just a simple method which will give you an idea to expand and customize for your logic. I hope this helps :-)

- Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxrub/